ctags ignores typescript class members after class member inline initialization with function call
Given this typescript source fl.ts:
class MyClass {                                                                  
                                                                                 
    attributeBeforeInitializationLine: string;                                   
                                                                                 
    attributeInlineInitialization = myFunction();                                
                                                                                 
    attributeAfterInitializationLine: string;                                    
                                                                                 
    myfunction_1() {                                                             
        let y = 1;                                                               
    }                                                                            
                                                                                 
    myfunction_2() {                                                             
        let z = 1;                                                               
    }                                                                            
}                                                                                
                                                                                 
       

class MyClass_2 {                                                                
    attributeMyClass2: int;                                                      
}                                                                                


the tags file produced by the command
$ ctags --languages=typescript fl.ts

contains only the 3 tags MyClass, attributeBeforeInitializationLine, attributeInlineInitialization  of class MyClass   and not attributeAfterInitializationLine. The tags of MyClass_2 are in the tags file correctly
If I omit the parentheses in the initialization, i.e.
attributeWithInitialization = myFunction;

the tags are produced correctly.
The tag file in the first case:
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/                       
!_TAG_OUTPUT_EXCMD  mixed   /number, pattern, mixed, or combineV2/               
!_TAG_OUTPUT_FILESEP    slash   /slash or backslash/                             
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/                                 
!_TAG_PATTERN_LENGTH_LIMIT  96  /0 for no limit/                                 
!_TAG_PROC_CWD  /home/fl/tmp/   //                                               
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //                               
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/               
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/                          
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9.0   //                                               
MyClass fl.ts   /^class MyClass {$/;"   c                                        
MyClass_2   fl.ts   /^class MyClass_2 {$/;" c                                    
attributeBeforeInitializationLine   fl.ts   /^    attributeBeforeInitializationLine: string;$/;"    p   class:MyClass
attributeInlineInitialization   fl.ts   /^    attributeInlineInitialization = myFunction();$/;" p   class:MyClass
attributeMyClass2   fl.ts   /^    attributeMyClass2: int;$/;"   p   class:MyClass_2
y   fl.ts   /^        let y = 1;$/;"    v                                        
z   fl.ts   /^        let z = 1;$/;"    v                                        
                           


The two last lines (starting with y resp. z) show that ctags processes the rest of the class MyClass inspite of ignoring it's members (it's strange that tags are produced for the local variables y and z).
The tag file in the second case (I have omitted all comment lines but the last - they are the same as in the first case):
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9.0   //
MyClass fl.ts   /^class MyClass {$/;"   c                                        
MyClass_2   fl.ts   /^class MyClass_2 {$/;" c                                    
attributeAfterInitializationLine    fl.ts   /^    attributeAfterInitializationLine: string;$/;" p   class:MyClass
attributeBeforeInitializationLine   fl.ts   /^    attributeBeforeInitializationLine: string;$/;"    p   class:MyClass
attributeInlineInitialization   fl.ts   /^    attributeInlineInitialization = myFunction;$/;"   p   class:MyClass
attributeMyClass2   fl.ts   /^    attributeMyClass2: int;$/;"   p   class:MyClass_2
myfunction_1    fl.ts   /^    myfunction_1() {$/;"  m   class:MyClass            
myfunction_2    fl.ts   /^    myfunction_2() {$/;"  m   class:MyClass            
          


If I put the definition of attributeAfterInitializationLine before the inline initialization, i.e.
class MyClass {                                                                  
                                                                                 
    attributeBeforeInitializationLine: string;                                   
                                                                                 
    attributeAfterInitializationLine: string;                                    
                                                                                 
    attributeInlineInitialization = myFunction();                                
                                                                                 
    myfunction_1() {                                                             
        let y = 1;                                                               
    }                                                                            
                                                                                 
    myfunction_2() {                                                             
        let z = 1;                                                               
    }                                                                            
}                                                                                
                                                                                 
class MyClass_2 {                                                                
    attributeMyClass2: int;                                                      
}                                                                                


a tags for attributeAfterInitializationLine is generated correctly as the tags file shows, but myfunction_1 and myfunction_2 are missing:
       
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9.0   //                                               
MyClass fl.ts   /^class MyClass {$/;"   c                                        
MyClass_2   fl.ts   /^class MyClass_2 {$/;" c                                    
attributeAfterInitializationLine    fl.ts   /^    attributeAfterInitializationLine: string;$/;" p   class:MyClass
attributeBeforeInitializationLine   fl.ts   /^    attributeBeforeInitializationLine: string;$/;"    p   class:MyClass
attributeInlineInitialization   fl.ts   /^    attributeInlineInitialization = myFunction();$/;" p   class:MyClass
attributeMyClass2   fl.ts   /^    attributeMyClass2: int;$/;"   p   class:MyClass_2
y   fl.ts   /^        let y = 1;$/;"    v                                        
z   fl.ts   /^        let z = 1;$/;"    v                                        


It looks as if ctags stops generating class members after having read the attributeInlineInitialization line. The behaviour is obviously independent of my .ctags file, because the remaining tags are correctly recognized if I omit the () in the inline initialization. The exit code of the ctags command is always 0.
Thanks for any help in advance!

When you say "exits prematurely", it means that no other material in the entire file is processed after that. Is that the case? Or is it just the attributeAfterInitialization from that MyClass item that is missing?

Yes, no other material in the entire file is processed

@Kaz: My comment above is wrong. Thank you for the question. I have improved my question.

Meanwhile a found an issue on github (unfortunately with a misleading title) https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/3827 which is a special case of the problem above.
